# C# XDocument: Find Attribute by another Attribute

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file:

```
<items>
    <item att='101' some='myStr1' />
    <item att='102' some='myStr2' />
    <item att='103' some='myStr3' />
</items>
```

and I have my XDocument:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("my.xml");
```

How can I get `'myStr2'` by finding `att='102'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
XElement item = xdoc.Root.Elements("item").FirstOrDefault(i => (string)i.Attribute("att") == "102");
if (item != null) 
{ 
  string s = (string)item.Attribute("some");
}
else
{
  // treat case that no matching item was found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Attribute method

```
doc.XPathSelectElement("/items/item[att='102']").Attributes().First(o=> o.Name == "some").Value;
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution requires an additional using statement to `System.Xml.XPath`, as `XPathSelectElement` is an extension method in that namespace.